# Cannot load assets with laravel mix() function in laravel 5.4 with VueJS

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2

I am using VueJS in Laravel 5.4. I have installed vue dependencies with `npm install`. running `npm run watch` or `npm run dev` the code compiled successfully. The problem I am having is loading assets from **resources/assets/**

This is what I have done in my blade:

```
<head>
...
    <link href="{{mix('/css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
....
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{mix('/js/app.js')}}"></script>

</body>
```

I am getting the following error:

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) for app.js and and app.css**

Replacing **mix()** with **asset()**, will load stylesheets correctly but ***app.js*** will be loaded from ***public/js/app.js*** instead of **resource/assets/js/app.js**

What am I doing wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't load assets from the resources directory. All your scripts, styles, images,etc. should be located in `public`. Mix by default will read your `js` files from `resources/assests/js` and move them to `public` after running them through the build pipeline.

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
```

That's the out of the box webpack setup in fresh laravel installations.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I modified my webpack.mix.js as so: mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js/').extract(['vue'])
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css'); and included the all the three files in my blade as so: <script src="{{asset('/js/manifest.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/js/vendor.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/js/app.js')}}"></script> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'matched' of undefined"

(found in <Root>), any guidanace?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue as me, I changed to below code then it's working.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/css/app.css') }}">
<script src=" {{ asset('js/app.js') }} "></script>
```

Comment: Would you like to add some explanation to your code-only-answer?

Comment: actually I don't know why...
But in my case,

when I use mix(), console log  shows this path, "http://localhost/js/app.js ".

But when I use asset(), the path is "http://localhost/laravue/public/js/app.js".

And my setting in webpack.mix.js is

    mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css'); 

I don't care...
maybe we need to modify mix setting in webpack.mix.js ?